# Why is not celery executing periodic task?

Tags: python, django, celery

Apologies if my question is too basic, But unfortunately i couldn't understand how to use periodic tasks properly from official documentation/tutorial.

I wanted to create periodic task executing function every 300 seconds (5 minutes), deleting all objects of model `Trades` which have existed longer than 300 seconds.

So i simply created a file called `tasks.py` under Project/Home directory (directory which consists of models.py, urls.py, views.py and etc.)

And i added this script:

```
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
from Home.models import Trades
import datetime


@periodic_task(run_every=300) # Run every 5 minutes.
    def remove_old():
        for i in Trades.objects.all():
            time_now = timezone.now()
            time_generated = i.generation_date
            time_elapsed = time_now - time_generated
            if int(time_elapsed.total_seconds()) > 300: # If an object has existed longer than 5 minutes, It must be deleted.
                i.remove()
```

For some reason, no objects were deleted after 5 minutes, Even though they were generated yesterday, I'm sure they are older than 300 seconds.

What could the problem be? Is there something with my code?

Comment: Did you run celerybeat process? Celery periodic job is triggered by celerybeat deamon.->  celery -A proj beat
Ref: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: @CKChen Thanks for response, I haven't, should i type `celery -A Home beat`? where Home is application which includes tasks.py..

Comment: Yes, it should work after you start the celerybeat process.

Comment: @CKChen Sorry for late response, Once i tried `celery -A Home beat`, It gave me this error: `ImportError: No module named celery`. Then i tried - `celery -A tasks` inside Home directory and got this error - `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either de
fine the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings`

Comment: You use Django with Celery? Please read celery official doc for how to construct a well-designed folder structure and setting files with Django.
doc: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: @CKChen Thanks, Now it returned this after executing `celery -A Home beat` - `celery beat v4.0.2 (latentcall) is starting.
LocalTime -> 2017-05-26 10:42:27
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%WARNING
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)` But task wasn't working...

Comment: Are you also run celery worker? You need to start both celery workers and celerybeat process to make it work.